# Slow Responsiveness MySql

Tags: mysql, innodb, semaphore

I have fired a command SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; in mysql for detecting slowness in response,  following is the stacktrace of Semaphore, but as I am new to this, so can't figure out statistics, please let me know if we can trace something from it.

```
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 22124, signal count 103334
Mutex spin waits 2140674, rounds 1742014, OS waits 8304
RW-shared spins 24931, OS waits 4171; RW-excl spins 1775, OS waits 8282
Spin rounds per wait: 0.81 mutex, 10.20 RW-shared, 210.67 RW-excl
```

Comment: This might be better suited at the DBA site? It does not really seem like a programming problem to me. Also, you might want to go back to your old questions and follow up on them. Accept answers that you've used, give points to helpfull answers, add your own solution, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look the [MySQL documentation for InnoDB Monitors](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-monitors.html). It says:

> This [SEMAPHORES] section reports threads waiting for a semaphore and statistics on
>   how many times threads have needed a spin or a wait on a mutex or a
>   rw-lock semaphore. A large number of threads waiting for semaphores
>   may be a result of disk I/O, or contention problems inside InnoDB.
>   Contention can be due to heavy parallelism of queries or problems in
>   operating system thread scheduling.

Comment: I have seen the documentation but i am concerned about the stats which it showing, are they really causing slowness ?

Comment: Hard to say.. The stats never cause slowness, they only indicate that there is maybe a problem. Try to following the tips from MySQL experts, for example in the O'Reilly Boook "High Performance MySQL" 1. find potential bottlenecks by benchmarking, profiling and  inspecting slow query logs. 2. try to optimize your database shema and indices 3. try to optimize the performance of your queries by retrieving only the data that you need in the fastest possible way.